# Appscript Google is not opening

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been attempting to reach script.google.com, but for the past three hours, I have been encountering the following error:

"Google Docs encountered an error. Please attempt to reload this page or revisit it in a few minutes.

To gain more insights into the Google Docs editors, please visit our help center.

We apologize for any inconvenience.

- The Google Docs Team"